# I can't drag and drop elements after the update

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022

Before the update, I can drag and drop elements with ease in the design area. Now with the new update, I just can't simply do it. How to fix this one?

Answer (score 3):

I been using vs2022 with webforms - no issues.

Since I have previous vs versions installed, it seems my settings might perhaps "stick" better, but check this setting:

tools->options

Then expand Web Forms Designer, and on general, choose this:

[image]

So, setting above to use Legacy Web Forms designer should fix this.

The live preview is actually a BIG new feature in vs2022 for web forms, but regardless, try above.